# How to retrieve login name of a user from Active Directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I want to retrieve the login name of a user from Active Directory.

For example the name is 'Jan Van der Linden'
After giving this name as parameter I must get his login name in return for example jvdlinden

Comment: i edit my answer .. please check it again

Comment: You've already accepted an answer.  If you wish to improve this question, edit it.  If you have a new issue, ask a new question.

Comment: some people did post answers that I didn't ask for. Finally marc_s came with a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
public string GetLoginName(string userName)
{
  // set up domain context
  PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

  // find user by name
  UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);

  if(user != null)
       return user.SamAccountName;
  else
       return string.Empty;
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD:

Comment: Hey marc_s,
do you know why I'm getting this error? 

The (&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(|(userPrincipalName=)(distinguishedName=)(name=))) search filter is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

using .net library you can use the following code to get username or any info from active directory

```
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.DirectoryServices;

ManagementObjectSearcher Usersearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem Where (Name LIKE 'ws%' or Name LIKE 'it%')"); 
            ManagementObjectCollection Usercollection = Usersearcher.Get(); 
            string[] sep = { "\\" };
            string[] UserNameDomain = Usercollection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"].ToString().Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

i add "Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem Where (Name LIKE 'ws%' or Name LIKE 'it%')"
this will get the user name by the full name

hope this could help you

Comment: where do I give the full name as parameter?

Comment: You can't - this returns the current logged in user

Comment: no that's not what I want. I want to give the fullname as parameter and get the login name.

Comment: you have to user the select statment to get the login name you want by the full name

Comment: you can use "Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem Where (Name LIKE 'ws%' or Name LIKE 'it%')" it will get the login name by the name ..... see my edit on my answer

Comment: please peacmaker are you serious? I don't see where you connect to Active Directory in the code?

Comment: @peacmaker the UserName property of From Win32_ComputerSystem is the Name of a user that is logged on currently (or the Console user if connecting using TS)

Comment: You should use DirectoryEntry, mentioned by Davide Piras. It's way more complete.

Answer (score 1):

this actually does almost the opposite but can be a starting point to check and modify as needed:

[Finding a User in Active Directory with the Login Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161398/finding-a-user-in-active-directory-with-the-login-name)

Answer (score 1):

Check this link has needed code snipple

[Validate AD-LDAP USer](http://akshaya-m.blogspot.com/2011/12/validate-login-user-with-adldap.html)

```
using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry())
        {
            entry.Username = "DOMAIN\\LOGINNAME";
            entry.Password = "PASSWORD";
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            searcher.Filter = "(objectclass=user)";
            try
            {
                searcher.FindOne();
                {
                    //Add Your Code if user Found..
                }
            }
            catch (COMException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ErrorCode == -2147023570)
                {
                    ex.Message.ToString();
                    // Login or password is incorrect 
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without Identity:

```
private string GetLogonFromDisplayName(string displayName)
{
    var search = new DirectorySearcher(string.Format("(&(displayname={0})(objectCategory=user))", displayName));
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");

    SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
    if (result != null)
    {
        var logonNameResults = result.Properties["sAMAccountName"];
        if (logonNameResults == null || logonNameResults.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return logonNameResults[0].ToString();
    }

    return null;
}
```