# Get All user from active directory C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get more than 1000 records from a DirectorySearcher in Asp.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90652/can-i-get-more-than-1000-records-from-a-directorysearcher-in-asp-net)
>   [c# Active Directory Services findAll() returns only 1000 entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488394/c-sharp-active-directory-services-findall-returns-only-1000-entries)

I have a problem when trying read all user from AD. Active directory contain over 3000 user, but I can read only 1000. This is my code

```
public DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldap, userName, password);
public DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);

var allUsers = directorySearcher.FindAll();
```

Comment: If the limit were arbitrary or a non-round number, I'd grant that this was a good question. But as it stands, a quick Google / SO search might have saved you the trouble. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90652/can-i-get-more-than-1000-records-from-a-directorysearcher-in-asp-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a user settings problem. According to this [page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/22cff477-18f0-4993-9627-a9871aaf73a2/) you have to set the page size to 1000 to get more than 1000 results:

> OmegaMan: Ya its bizarre, one has to set a page size as 1000 to get more records than 1000. This is a trick/issue one doesn't forget due to the way one has to resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was with pageSize. I put the pageSize on 1000 and now work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `PageSize` property on your `DirectorySearcher` to get *paged searching* and more than 1000 rows back:

```
public DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldap, userName, password);

public DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
directorySearcher.PageSize = 500;  // ADD THIS LINE HERE !

var allUsers = directorySearcher.FindAll();
```