# Which LDAP Membership Provider should I choose for ASP.NET MVC 4 Enterprise Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, ldap, soa, membership-provider

I'm starting an enterprise application that claims authentication using Active Directory users data. It will be like a Frontend Controller for every service that request company's and workers personal information, like SOA's style. But I need to decide which is the appropiate for this task.

Does anyone has utilized any of these somewhere?
I appreciate any help given.

I've consulted several sources, mainly the Nuget Package Manager official website page for [LDAP Membership Providers](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Home/Search?q=ldap).
These are quoted:

- **nJupiter.DataAccess.Ldap**
- **Craig's Utility Library LDAP Namespace**
- **LINQ to LDAP**
- **Zetetic.Ldap**
- **OGD LDAP Active Directory Providers**

Comment: Why would you use ldap if you want to connect to AD? Support for AD is already part of .net

Comment: For an example of consuming active directory service in .net see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488394/c-sharp-active-directory-services-findall-returns-only-1000-entries

Comment: I'll consult your recommendation. I have another doubt, as a developer station, do I need special rights to query AD for other user's fields ? Are there any extra permissions that I should be aware of?

Comment: Depends on your requirements, for mostly read only access you may or may not need additional access ( domain admin ) depending on how your domain is configured

Comment: Is there any website for technical specifications that illustrate some use cases of LDAP scenarios and models those security requirements. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Before selecting an ldap provider, look at the native support that is built into .net

See the msdn documentation for There are two ways around this limitation - see the MSDN docs on DirectorySearcher for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher(v=vs.110).aspx