# How to retrieve all users of Active Directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ldap

I use following code to retrieve `all` users of active directory but `not all users` retrieved. Should I include something else in `Filter`?
 this is simplified code.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + Bous.DomainName, Bous.UserName, Bous.Password);
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
mySearcher.Filter = ("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))");

foreach (SearchResult result in mySearcher.FindAll())
{
     dr = dt.NewRow();
     ResultPropertyCollection myResultPropColl = result.Properties;
     dr[0] = myResultPropColl["samaccountname"][0].ToString() + "@" + Bous.DomainName;
     dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: AFAIK there is a limit regarding number of entities can be retrieved from AD. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488394/c-sharp-active-directory-services-findall-returns-only-1000-entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + Bous.DomainName, Bous.UserName, Bous.Password);
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
mySearcher.PageSize = 1000;   // <--- Important!
mySearcher.Filter = ("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))");

foreach (SearchResult result in mySearcher.FindAll())
{
     dr = dt.NewRow();
     ResultPropertyCollection myResultPropColl = result.Properties;
     dr[0] = myResultPropColl["samaccountname"][0].ToString() + "@" + Bous.DomainName;
     dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for UserPrincipal (users)
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
   }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System.DirectoryServices;
    using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
    ...
    protected static UserPrincipal QueryFilterUsers(string FilterFullName, string FilterDescription, string FilterLogin, string FilterPhone, string FilterEmail)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _Domain);
        UserPrincipal _UserPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

        _UserPrincipal.SamAccountName = "*" + ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterLogin)) ? FilterLogin.Trim() + "*" : "");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterFullName)) _UserPrincipal.DisplayName = "*" + FilterFullName.Trim() + "*";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterDescription)) _UserPrincipal.Description = "*" + FilterDescription.Trim() + "*";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterPhone)) _UserPrincipal.VoiceTelephoneNumber = "*" + FilterPhone.Trim() + "*" ;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterEmail)) _UserPrincipal.EmailAddress = "*" + FilterEmail.Trim() + "*";
        return _UserPrincipal;
    }

    //Получение списков
    public static List<Principal> GetUsersPrincipalList(string FilterFullName, string FilterDescription, string FilterLogin, string FilterPhone, string FilterEmail)
    {
        PrincipalSearcher _PrincipalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
        _PrincipalSearcher.QueryFilter = QueryFilterUsers(FilterFullName, FilterDescription, FilterLogin, FilterPhone, FilterEmail);
        (_PrincipalSearcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher).PageSize = _PageSize;
        (_PrincipalSearcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher).SizeLimit = _SizeLimit;

        return _PrincipalSearcher.FindAll().ToList();
    }
```