# Active Directory Search not returning all users

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I have code to populate a user id dropdown list within a VB.net application. Some user names are not being returned. I'm getting more than 1000 returned so it does not appear to be the 1000 limit. If I add (sAMAccountName=Kry*) to the search filter, then the user (whose name starts with kry) that was not appearing does get returned. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Private Sub PopSecurityUser()
    cboUser.Items.Clear()

    Dim SearchRoot As DirectoryEntry = ActiveDirectory.Forest.GetCurrentForest.RootDomain.GetDirectoryEntry '< More portable. Discover domain root DirectoryEntry rather than hard coding a Global Catalog.
    Dim AdObj As System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult

    Dim Searcher As New DirectorySearcher(SearchRoot)

    With Searcher
        .PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName")
        .SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
        .Filter = "(&(!objectClass=contact)(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"  '< Exclude contacts because they don't have a sAMAccountName property.
        .ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All    '< Causes lookups to follow LDAP referrals if the object doesn't exist on the queried domain controller.
    End With

    For Each AdObj In Searcher.FindAll
        If Not IsNumeric(AdObj.Properties("sAMAccountName")(0).ToString.Substring(0, 1)) Then
            cboUser.Items.Add(AdObj.Properties("sAMAccountName")(0))
        End If
    Next

    cboUser.Sorted = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The [DirectorySearcher.SizeLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.sizelimit.aspx) property is set to 1,000 by default. I found another StackOverflow question regarding this exact situation and apparently there are two workarounds. The StackOverflow answer that I am referring to is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3488957/1920035

Comment: I was getting 1232 users so I don't think it was the 1000 limit. I ended up adding (userAccountControl=512) to exclude disabled accounts and now I get about 800 rows returned, including the users that were missing.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I must have overlooked the "... more than 1,000 returned" statement somehow. Nonetheless, I'm glad that you were able to find a solution.