# Querying users incrementally from Active Directory from C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directorysearcher

I'm trying to load users incrementally from Active Directory which has a lot of users. (My memory can't hold all the data.)

I tried to use the DirectorySearcher.VirtualListView property to retrieve a portion of users each time, but it seems like the Server is not able to sort such a big amount of data. And it's giving me an error message:

> The server does not support the requested critical extension

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you google it?

Comment: I did, but couldn't find a solution

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Why not have a clustered index on the users and use OFFSET with FETCHNEXT

Answer (score 0):

By default, DirectorySearcher is limited to 1,000 items, and if you need to return more, read *[Can I get more than 1000 records from a DirectorySearcher in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90652/can-i-get-more-than-1000-records-from-a-directorysearcher-in-asp-net)*.

AD/LDAP should not be used to sort, search, etc. for large data to avoid affecting the performance of the server. Consider to use a database where you could load all objects/users from AD and where you could then query the data from.